# Limma to Compare Bulk RNA Seq using makeContrasts and eBayes

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, rna-seq, limma

After a day of googling, I've decided that it'd be better to ask the question here.

So the experiment is I have bulk RNA seq data from 3 patients: A, B, C.
And their RNA seq data is obtained for pre-treatment, treatment cycle 1, treatment cycle 2, treatment cycle 3.

So in total I have 12 samples of bulk RNA seq:

- A.PreTreat   ->   A.Cycle1 -> A.Cycle2 -> A.Cycle3
- B.PreTreat   ->   B.Cycle1 -> B.Cycle2 -> B.Cycle3
- C.PreTreat   ->   C.Cycle1 -> C.Cycle2 -> C.Cycle3

I want to get a differential gene list between different cycles (i.e. cycle 3 to pretreatment, cycle 3 to cycle 2) using `model.matrix(), lmFit(), makeContrasts(), contrasts.fit(), eBayes()`, all of which are in the limma package.

Here is my minimal working example.

```
library(limma)
# Already normalized expression set: rows are genes, columns are the 12 samples
normalized_expression <- matrix(data=sample(1:100), nrow=10, ncol=12)
colnames(normalized_expression) <- c("A.PreTreat", "A.Cycle1", "A.Cycle2", "A.Cycle3", "B.PreTreat", "B.Cycle1", "B.Cycle2", "B.Cycle3", "C.PreTreat", "C.Cycle1", "C.Cycle2", "C.Cycle3")

patient_and_treatment <- factor(colnames(normalized_expression), levels = colnames(normalized_expression))

design.matrix <- model.matrix(~0 + patient_and_treatment)
colnames(design.matrix) <- patient_and_treatment
fit <- lmFit(normalized_expression, design.matrix)

# I want to get a contrast matrix to get differential genes between cycle 3 treatment and pre-treatment in all patients
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts("A.Cycle3+B.Cycle3+C.Cycle3-A.PreTreat-B.PreTreat-C.PreTreat",
                                 levels = levels(patient_and_treatment))

# Outputs Error of no residual degree of freedom
fit2 <- eBayes( contrasts.fit( fit, contrast.matrix ) )

# Want to run but cannot
summary(decideTests(fit2))
```

So far I am stuck on no residual degree of freedom error.

I am not even sure if this is the statistically right way in limma to address my question of getting differential gene list between cycle 3 treatment to pre-treatment in all patients.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 1 observation per group, this makes the regression meaningless as you are fitting each data point to itself.

Briefly, what you are looking for is common effects observed across all patients, for say Cycle3 compared to PreTreat and so on, set up the model like this:

```
library(limma)

metadata = data.frame(
Patient=gsub("[.][^ ]*","",colnames(normalized_expression)),
Treatment=gsub("^[A-Z][.]*","",colnames(normalized_expression))
)

   Patient    Treatment
1        A PreTreat
2        A   Cycle1
3        A   Cycle2
4        A   Cycle3
5        B PreTreat
6        B   Cycle1
7        B   Cycle2
8        B   Cycle3
9        C PreTreat
10       C   Cycle1
11       C   Cycle2
12       C   Cycle3
```

Now specify the model matrix, the Patient term is to account for differences in starting levels between Patients:

```
design.matrix <- model.matrix(~0 + Treatment+Patient,data=metadata)
fit <- lmFit(normalized_expression, design.matrix)
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(TreatmentCycle3-TreatmentPreTreat,
TreatmentCycle1-TreatmentPreTreat,levels=design.matrix)
fit2 = contrasts.fit(fit, contrast.matrix)
fit2 = eBayes(fit2)
```

You can check that the coefficients give you what you wanted:

```
fit2$coefficients
       Contrasts
        TreatmentCycle3 - TreatmentPreTreat
   [1,]                           -3.666667
   [2,]                          -13.666667
   [3,]                            1.666667
   [4,]                          -40.666667
   [5,]                           12.000000
   [6,]                          -46.000000
   [7,]                          -32.000000
   [8,]                            4.666667
   [9,]                           11.333333
  [10,]                            5.666667
       Contrasts
        TreatmentCycle1 - TreatmentPreTreat
   [1,]                           -11.33333
   [2,]                           -19.33333
   [3,]                           -27.33333
   [4,]                           -42.33333
   [5,]                            27.33333
   [6,]                           -32.66667
   [7,]                           -33.00000
   [8,]                           -30.66667
   [9,]                            46.00000
  [10,]                            17.33333
```

Comment: Would you tell me what you mean by "cannot have more than one observation per group"? 

To be honest, I do not even know what this model matrix is for aside from each row represents the sample and the 1s correspond to the "factor" the samples belong to.

Comment: Hi! So the model you wrote, you have a total number of 12 factors, one for every observation. This means fitting one mean for every observation and it is not a regression or at. Hence it complained "no residual degree of freedom error".

Comment: With limma and others, you are trying to model the effects of gene expression, and saying it can be explained by factor A, B, C (treatment and patient in your case). The model matrix basically tells the linear model, estimate the effects from these samples.

Comment: Is it possible to make a contrast model for this to compare Patient C's Cycle 1 treatment to Patient C's Pretreatment?

Comment: As you have seen from the error, you cannot do limma without replicates. You are comparing 1 sample vs 1 sample. How do you measure error and stuff? You can see https://www.biostars.org/p/74155/ for more discussion.

Comment: @StupidWolf really helpful stuff .I was looking how to make contrast in limma now I understand how to write it